# Can array names be considered as variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is just a really quick question which I can't find the answer to in Google, is the name of an array also a variable? 
So for example I have the following array:

```
var cars = ["Rover", "Ford", "BMW"];
```

can cars be considered as a variable?

Comment: Cars is a variable. You could reassign cars to = ["Buick", "Volkswagen"]

Comment: Thank you! That's all I wanted!

Comment: By the way if I have index = 0 which access elements in the array, will index be considered as a variable?

Comment: yes it will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course `cars` is a variable.

You can do:

```
var cars = ["Rover", "Ford", "BMW"];
cars = 100;
cars = 'hello';
```

Comment: So if I have index = 0 which will access the first element in the array if I am not mistaken, will index be considered as a variable?

Comment: If your code is: `var index = 0; cars[index];` Yes it is definately a variable